# Which elementary particles have been seen up to now?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, elementary-particles

Which [elementary particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) have been shown up to now?
which one except Graviton, haven't seen?
I need an update one, I am searching but I couldn't find. If anyone could answer me, I am so thankful.

Comment: the ones in the elementary particle table are considered as "seen", where not only eyes but data using instruments and the standard model fit  on data are taken into account https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg

Answer (score 1):

Elementary particles are classified into two groups: Bosons & Fermions.
Fermions comes with two families: quarks and leptons. Leptons come with three generations (till date no fourth generation leptons observed). Same is true for quarks as well.The first generation consists of electron $e^{-}$ and electron-neutrino $\tau_{e}$. Standard way of representing them goes as follows
\begin{equation}
L_{e} = \begin{bmatrix} \nu_{e}\\e^{-} \end{bmatrix}\qquad L_{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix} \nu_{\mu}\\ \mu^{-} \end{bmatrix}\qquad L_{\tau} = \begin{bmatrix} \nu_{\tau}\\ \tau^{-} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Where $L_{e}$ stands for electron family (or first generation), $L_{mu}$ stands for muon family (or second generation) and $L_{\tau}$ stands for tauon family (or third generation) of leptons. Each of these elementary particles has been discovered, with their anti-particles as well.

Likewise quark family can be shown by
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} u\\d \end{bmatrix}\qquad \begin{bmatrix} c\\s \end{bmatrix}\qquad \begin{bmatrix} t\\b \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Where $u,d,c,s,t,b$ stands for up, down, charm, strange, top and botton. All these quarks has been found (remember that quarks are confined inside hadrons) with their respective anti-particles. Till date no free quark has been observed.

Fermions described above interact by mediating gauge bosons. Here is the list

Electromagnetic interaction mediated by photon, Status-Observed.
Strong interactions mediated by glouns, Status: Observed.
Weak interactions mediated by $W^{\pm}, Z^{0}$, Status: Observed.
Gravity (speculated) mediated by: graviton, Status: not observed.

Masses of all known elementary particles come from mechanism known as spontaneous symmetry breaking which triggered by Higgs boson. its just found back in 2012.

For more informations you can consult with particle data group (PDG).